# Sort users by nos of students of their courses self referential

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I hav a rails app with user model,and a course model.
User has_many courses and courses has_many students(users).
How do I sort the users by total number of students they have among all courses by them.
I tried something like

```
User.joins(:courses).group('users.id').order("COUNT(course.users) DESC")
```

but it didnt work.How do i achieve this?
Course.rb

```
  class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
      searchkick
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :category
      has_many :coursejoins, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "learnable_id"
      has_many :students, through: :coursejoins, class_name: "User"
      has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
      ..
```

User.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      searchkick
      has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :coursejoins, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "student_id"
      has_many :learnables, through: :coursejoins, class_name: "Course"
      has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
      before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
      validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 40 }
      ..
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution below? Is it close to what you were looking for SiD Devesh?

Comment: Sorry for late response, i was looking into `counter_cache`...my user model is bit different actually so wasn't sure this will work...I will update my question with my user and course models...can you tell me if it will still work... @RodrigoMartinez

Comment: The counter_cache caches count(*) of a specific association on a database attribute, the idea behind what I told you is to have a database attribute on courses table so that you can order by it (or in this case by a function applied to it). Having said that you have to put the counter on a specific association, in this case it looks like it would be `has_many :students, through: :coursejoins, class_name: "User", counter_cache: true` and add `students_count` to `courses` table instead of what I posted on my original answer - and in the query use `sum(courses.students_count)` instead.

Comment: thanks...one thing...what migration i will have to learn to add students_count to courses table?...sorry relatively new to rails@RodrigoMartinez...

Comment: `bin/rails g migration AddStudentsCountToCourses students_count:integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat overly complex but this is something you could do:

Add to your Course model the following to cache count of users on each course:

```
has_many :users, through: :students, counter_cache: true
```

You then need to add the column `users_count` to `courses` table and you'll probably need to initialize the counters so look for [reset_counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters) method.

After this I think this query should work:

```
User.joins(:courses).select("users.id, sum(courses.users_count)").group('users.id').order("sum(courses.users_count)")
```

Comment: it worked but counter_cache had to be added to coursejoin model as `belongs_to :learnable, :class_name => "Course", :counter_cache => :students_count`...then the query works

Comment: also select had to be removed from query...`User.joins(:courses).group('users.id').order("sum(courses.students_count)")`

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped!